# Var in RegExp doesn't work in javascript email vaditation

Tags: javascript, php

This piece of code suppose to let user inserts a new record if the email is end with @test.com, and it should return false and show alert "Please Enter Correct Email Domain" if the email does not end with @test.com. However, the current code always let user inserts a new record no matter the email end with @test.com or not end with @test.com. There isn't any error message. Here is the code and I hope someone can see what's wrong:

```
var javaScriptVar = "test.com";
var regex = new RegExp("@" + javaScriptVar + "\\s*$"); 
if(!regex.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value){
         alert("Please Enter Correct Email Domain"); 
            return false;
        }
```

I had this direct `.test` way to do it and it works, but this way cannot let me insert a variable:
`if (!(/@test.com\s*$/.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value))) {`

Comment: Except that the `.` in `test.com` is unescaped (and therefore stands for _any character_, matching `testXcom`) your pattern works for me. Where are you calling the `return false`? We can't see the full context of this function, and it may be a logic problem outside this code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just try `var javaScriptVar = "test\.com";` but it still just lets me insert the record even with email that doesn't end with @test.com

Comment: Right - it is possibly due to `return false;` not preventing execution of whatever you expect it to prevent. Please include some info about what event this code is bound to, and how you have wrapped it in a function.

Comment: I just try again and check my old codes. This is the only way I can make the code works: `if (!(/@test.com\s*$/.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value))) {`

Comment: and `return false'` works with the `if (!(/@test.com\s*$/.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value))) {`, so I think it is not the `return false` problem.

Comment: It would be better if you can reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so people can make changes and test. Perhaps you can find the problem yourself while building the fiddle!